# Problem with dataset when table does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, dataset, ado.net

I get an `error` when the `wrong credential` is entered but if I enter a true credential then I do not get an error.

See my login screen: if I enter true credential then I do not get any error

[image]

But if I enter the wrong credential then **I get an error because the second table does not exist**

[image]

The error is `Cannot find table 1`

[image]

`HomeController.cs`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExecutiveLogin(int? exuserid, string exusername)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("executivelogin", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@executiveid", exuserid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@executivetypename", exusername);
    cn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Error Message";
    ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Customer Data";

    var message = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
    //object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    List<Customer> query = null;
    if (ds.Tables[0].TableName == "Error Message")
    {
        ViewBag.errormessage = message;

        var Customerdata = (from DataRow row in ds.Tables[1].Rows
        select new Customer
        {
                    CustomerName = row["CustomerName"].ToString(),
                            Type = row["type"].ToString(),
        });
        query = Customerdata.ToList();

        ViewBag.custdata = query;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.errormessage = message;
    }

    return View();

}
```

if I enter a true credential then not give an error and I enter the wrong credential then give an error

Comment: I did not understand what's the problem in here. Could you please ask it with **what**, **how** or **why** keyword ?

Comment: @ahmetgül sorry my English is bad if i enter the wrong credential then it give an error because second table not return from the store procedure and that's why give an error but how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the `count` in `dataset`, then set name for second table.

`ds.Tables.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Customer Data" : /*No second datatable */;`

Answer (score 2):

If the user exists, you are executing two `SELECT` statements, so there are two `DataTables` in your `DataSet`. If the user doesn't exist, you're only executing one `SELECT` statement, so there's only one `DataTable`, so index 1 is out of range. You should be checking the contents of the first `DataTable` first, to see whether the login was successful, or else just check the number of `DataTables` first. Only if there is a second `DataTable`, should you try to get that second `DataTable`.